# Подскажите, как реализовать переход с другой страницы сайта на главную и сразу открыть нужный таб

Tags: javascript, tab, location.hash

```js
const tabs = (tabSelector, tabContentSelector, anchorSelector) => {
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(tabSelector),
        tabContents = document.querySelectorAll(tabContentSelector);
    const anchor = document.querySelectorAll(anchorSelector);
    tabs.forEach((tab, i) => {
        tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
            inactiveTab();
            tab.classList.add('active');
            hideContent();
            showContent(i);
        });
    });

    function hideContent() {
        tabContents.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('show');
            item.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
    if (tabs.length > 1) {
        anchor.forEach((item, i) => {
            item.addEventListener('click', () => {
             
                hideContent();
                showContent(i);
                inactiveTab(i);
                tabs[i].classList.add('active');
                

            })
        })
    }


    function showContent(i = 0) {
        tabContents[i].style.display = 'block';
        tabContents[i].classList.add('show');
    }
    function inactiveTab() {
        tabs.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
    }
    hideContent();
    showContent(); 
 }; 
 
 export default tabs;
 
 //вот тут функция табов вызывается
 
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    Slick();
    button();

    form('https://stalbr.ru/mail.php');
    navbar();

    try {
        tabs('[data-tabs]', '.tabs-content', '.roof_anchor');
    } catch (error) {}
```

```html
<section class="production" id="production">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-12">
        <h3>Продукция</h3>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-sm-12">
        <p>
          Ниже представлены некоторые стандартные изделия, которые мы предлагаем. Также производим любые изделия по вашим размерам.
          Материалы выполнения: оцинкованная сталь, нержавеющая сталь, алюминий, медь. Стандартная толщина металла от 0,35мм до 0,7мм. 
          Широкая цветовая гамма по каталогу RAL и текстур под дерево, более 100 оттенков. Одностороннее и двухстороннее покрытие.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <div class="nav nav-tabs">
        <button class="nav-link active tab-item btn-primary" data-tabs>Кровля</button>
        <button class="nav-link tab-item btn-primary" data-tabs>Фасад</button>
        <button class="nav-link tab-item btn-primary" data-tabs>Для бани</button>
        <button class="nav-link tab-item btn-primary" data-tabs>Другое</button>
        <a href="https://stalbr.ru/zabory/" class="nav-link tab-item btn-primary" style="color: white;">Забор Жалюзи</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Товары-->
    <!--1 ряд-->
    <div class="tabs-contents-wrapper">
      <div class="tabs-content fade show">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card-deck-wrapper">
              <div class="card-deck" id='roof'>
                <!-- content -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- фасады -->
      <div class="tabs-content fade">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card-deck-wrapper">
              <div class="card-deck" id="facade">
                <!-- content -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в функции tabs есть функция `showContent`. Можете вернуть её и использовать далее.

```
const tabs = (tabSelector, tabContentSelector, anchorSelector) => {
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(tabSelector);
  const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll(tabContentSelector);
  const anchor = document.querySelectorAll(anchorSelector);
  tabs.forEach((tab, i) => {
    tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
      inactiveTab();
      tab.classList.add('active');
      hideContent();
      showContent(i);
    });
  });

  function hideContent() {
    tabContents.forEach((item) => {
      item.classList.remove('show');
      item.style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
  if (tabs.length > 1) {
    anchor.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
        const tabTo = urlParams.get('tab');
        hideContent();
        showContent(i);
        inactiveTab(i);
        tabs[i].classList.add('active');
        console.log(urlParams);
        console.log(tabTo);
      });
    });
  }
  if (tabTo) {
    tabs.switchTabTo(tabTo);
  }

  function showContent(i = 0) {
    tabContents[i].style.display = 'block';
    tabContents[i].classList.add('show');
  }
  function inactiveTab() {
    tabs.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('active'));
  }
  hideContent();
  showContent();

  return {
    showContent
  }
};

export default tabs;

//вот тут функция табов вызывается

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  Slick();
  button();

  form('https://stalbr.ru/mail.php');
  navbar();

  try {
    const tab = tabs('[data-tabs]', '.tabs-content', '.roof_anchor');
    tab.showContent(/* индекс нужного таба */)
  } catch (error) {}
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) но подскажите, пожалуйста, какой индекс таба использовать, если они заданы одинаковыми data атрибутами data-tabs?